# laravel Ajax onChange select box Foreach result

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I created an ajax request to display results from my table eloquent query who depends one a select box "poule".

Everything is working but when I run the ajax request by selecting a `poule_id` from the select box I need to display the json result. I would like to display the result as my foreach loop in the table `($equipes as $equipe)` because as you can see I display value from models in relation.

Actually with this way I can only display **equipe_id** but i would like to display the object to access to the other models in relation and display the result as my foreach in the table like :

```
@foreach($equipes as $equipe)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="{!! route('club.show', $equipe->equipe->structure->id) !!}">{{$equipe->equipe->structure->nom_structure}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="{!! route('equipe.show', $equipe->equipe->id) !!}">{{$equipe->equipe->lb_equipe}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>{!! Form::text('nb_bonus') !!}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Hope someone understood what I want to do. thanks a lot in advance friends

My select filter search :

```
<select id="poule">
  @foreach($select_poules as $select_poule)
      <option value="{{$select_poule->id}}">{{$select_poule->lb_poule}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

My table :

```
<table id="equipes" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Club</th>
            <th>Nom de l'équipe</th>
            <th>Bonus(+/-)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($equipes as $equipe)
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="{!! route('club.show', $equipe->equipe->structure->id) !!}">{{$equipe->equipe->structure->nom_structure}}</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{!! route('equipe.show', $equipe->equipe->id) !!}">{{$equipe->equipe->lb_equipe}}</a>
            </td>
            <td>{!! Form::text('nb_bonus') !!}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My script :

```
<script>
    $(document).on('change', '#poule', function() {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            url : '/licences/public/search/equipes',
            data : {
                poule_id : $('#poule').val()
            },
            success:function(data){

                $('#equipes').empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.equipes.length; i++) {
                    $('#equipes').append('<tr><td>'+data.equipes[i].equipe_id+'</td></‌​tr>')
                }

            },
            timeout:10000
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does the object returned from the AJAX call contain the href values for the links in the table or do you need to make more calls (or obtain more information in the first AJAX call)?

Comment: i updated my code and i added my controller you will see that i make a query with a pivot table EquipePoule with (poule_id , equipe_id) with eloquent no worries i can access to the other models in relation but with json i only can display the equipe_id and poule_id